# Submit form to database via ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, post

I have created a dynamic display of Text Boxes from my database in .net web forms. 
Now I have to send their values back to the data base with new values when they are edited with ajax post method.

This is how the code looks:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="MainContent_gvAllValues" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
    <th scope="col" vAllValues</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl02vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value One" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl03vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Two" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl04vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Three" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvAllValues$ctl05vAllValues" type="text" value="RR Value Four" id="MainContent_gvAllValues_3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnButton" value="Button" id="MainContent_btnButton" />
```

This is the jquery I did so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

          $('#MainContent_btnButton').click(function () {
          var alltextBoxMessages = "";
          $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
              alltextBoxMessages = alltextBoxMessages + ' ' + $(this).val();
          });
          alert(alltextBoxMessages);
      });
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "/SecondPage.aspx",
                      data: "alltextBoxMessages;",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (msg) {

                      }
                  });

              });

        </script>
```

I managed to submit all the values with one click on the button and store it in the "alltextBoxMessages".

Can some one plase help me with the rest of the code regarding ajax ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: do you want to do the ajax call on submit?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax call should be inside click event, you are passing value to the data. So data format should be **data: alltextBoxMessages** instead of data: "alltextBoxMessages;"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#MainContent_btnButton').on('click', function() {
    var alltextBoxMessages = "";
    $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
      alltextBoxMessages = alltextBoxMessages + ' ' + $(this).val();
    });
    alert(alltextBoxMessages);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/SecondPage.aspx",
    data: alltextBoxMessages,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {

    }
  });
});

});
```

Comment: Thank for  help !
I have added a code for successful submission and for error.
And unfortunately I get message: 'An error ocurred' :/
Do you maybe know what is the problem ?

Here it is:

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/FirstPage.aspx",
    data: "alltextBoxMessages;",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Submission was successful.');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('An error occurred.');
        console.log(data);
    },
});

Comment: data should be like this, data: alltextBoxMessages,

Comment: Same thing : /
Here the img from my console:

[link](https://imgur.com/a/WwQ9q)

Maybe there something wrong with the message ?
[meta]
                      success: function (data) {
                          console.log('Submission was successful.');
                          console.log(data);
                      },
                      error: function (data) {
                          console.log('An error occurred.');
                          console.log(data);
                      },